# android studio2.0 error InvalidReferenceException when new a empty activity

Tags: android, android-studio

**when i create a new activity and click finish, it alert:**
event log :
`Error executing FreeMarker template: The following has evaluated to null or missing:`
`==> srcDir [in template "root://activities/common/common_globals.xml.ftl"`
 `at line 41, column 34]`
`Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing,`
`either specify a default value with myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use #if myOptionalVar??>when-present#else>when-missing#if>.`
 
`(These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthessis: (myOptionVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionVar.foo)?? The failing instruction (print stack trace for 1 more):`
`==> ${srcDir} [in template "root://activities/common/common_globals.xml.ftl" at line 41, column 32]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to Build->Clean project. That works for me well in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing this issue in a Udacity project, this is a know bug:

https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/issues/67

Similar issue also reported [here](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Sunshine/issues/24) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232076).

Proposed workaround is:

Remove the following configuration from your project build.gradle and then clicking on sync now

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(); 
if (osName.contains("windows")) { 
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}" 
}
```

Then close the project > Import the project again.

Comment: If I do that, I get this other error:Error:Failed to crunch file H:\Dropbox\workspace_AndroidStudio\_Udacity_2_ToyApp\Lesson06-Visualizer-Preferences\T06.01-Exercise-SetupTheActivity\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png into H:\Dropbox\workspace_AndroidStudio\_Udacity_2_ToyApp\Lesson06-Visualizer-Preferences\T06.01-Exercise-SetupTheActivity\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png